# money-rails set custom currency

Tags: currency

I am in a `rails 3.2.6` app using the gems money and money-rails.

For money-rails I have set-up an initializer with this data:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
    config.default_currency = :eur
    config.register_currency = {
        :id                  => :euc, 
        :priority            => 1,
        :iso_code            => "EUR",
        :name                => "Euro with Comma decimal mark",
        :symbol              => "€",
        :symbol_first        => true,
        :subunit             => "Cent",
        :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
        :thousands_separator => ".",
        :decimal_mark        => ","
    }
end
```

Note I have created a new currency :euc, because I want to display the euro currency with the comma decimal separator,

but the problem is the money object doesn't display yet the comma, for example:

```
amount = Money.new(100, 'EUR')

amount.to_s
```

or in a view:

```
<%= humanized_money amount %>

it display "1.00 instead of "1,00"
```

where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `amount.format(decimal_mark: ",")` for now. It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`100.to_money('EUR')`

`Money.new(100)` considers 100 to be in cents.